# Convert row with several columns into several rows with one column each

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have a very long list of data that looks like this:

```
User1    Item1    Item2    Item3

User2    Item1    Item2    #NUM! (This is a failed formula)

User3    Item1    #NUM!    #NUM!
```

And I want to turn each row into 1-3 different rows, like this:

```
User1    Item1
User1    Item2
User1    Item3
User2    Item1
User2    Item2
User3    Item1
```

Is there a way to do this natively in Excel? VBA solutions are fine as well.

Comment: [This link](http://superuser.com/q/964598/449500) has a couple of answers for a similar question

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2010 or 2013, I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  From Excel 2016, Power Query is built in to the Data ribbon under "Get and Transform" section.

Power Query can start from an Excel table. It has an "Unpivot other Columns" command on it's Transform ribbon, which will do what you are after.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098?ui=en-US

Comment: Unfortunately my work computer runs 2007 so I won't be able to use this addin. Thanks for bringing it to my attention though.